# Code difference between local and remote JSON code

Tags: angularjs

I have a local JSON file in my Angular app that works well. When I upload that file to my server and try to access it the data won't read. What needs changing?

```
.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', function($scope, $http, $state) {
        $http.get('http://example.com/remoteproducts.json').success(function(data) {
          $scope.products = data;
          $scope.whichproduct = $state.params.aId;
        });
}]);
```

Comment: try `$scope.products = JSON.parse(data.data);`

Comment: No joy with that, no display of products  ```XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://exmaple.com/remoteproducts.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin``` Is the error coming from the console in Chrome

Comment: Its a cors error.. you need to handle cors on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

This code works now

```
.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', function($scope, $http, $state) {
        $http.get('https://example.com/remoteproducts.json').success(function(data) {
          $scope.products = data;
          $scope.whichproduct = $state.params.aId;
        });
}]);
```

and viewable in the browser after installing this Chrome extension

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related?hl=en-US